# How to do a multi-level multi-module Sonar project with the Ant task?

Tags: sonarqube

There are plenty of examples of how to do multi-project Sonar projects with Ant.  However, what if the projects are nested multiple layers deep?  For example:

```
root
    Project A
        Subproject A1
        Subproject A2
    Project B
```

I want to generate a Sonar project that reflects the same structure as the projects, with Project A having showing the summarized view of A1 and A2.  However, I can't figure out what the resulting properties should look like to generate this project structure.

Answer (score 3):

It's all in how the sonar.modules properties are set.

Following my example, the properties might look like this:

```
sonar.modules=ProjectA,ProjectB
ProjectA.sonar.modules=SubprojectA,SubprojectB
```

The remaining properties for setting basedir, source dirs, etc. are just like any other sonar properties file.